# Django Grappelli not selecting all on clicking select all checkbox

Tags: django, django-admin, django-grappelli

I am having some issues on my admin panel which is powered by `django-grappelli`. When I click on the select all check-button, none of the items get selected.

[image: Grapelli not selecting all on clicking the select all check box]

Another issue is, when I select an action e.g. 'Delete selected items', after selecting some items, no `Go` or `Apply Action` is shown.

[image: <code>Go</code> or <code>Apply Action</code> button is missing after selecting items]

However both this problems get solved when I comment out `grappeli` in the `settings.py` file and use the default django admin panel.

Comment: You should first check for any Javascript errors using your browser's debugger (typically by pressing F12 before loading the page).

Comment: Yes, I believe that was Javascript errors. Do you use any custom javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `python manage.py collectstatic` and refresh your browser